# SQL Server 2008 shredding XML data - cant get element text in rowset!

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

Please consider this simple example.  I can't get the text of the state element 'red' or 'blue'  Please help!!!!! this is driving me batty

```
DECLARE @xml XML;

SET @xml = '<capitals>
  <state name="Alabama" 
    abbreviation="AL" 
    capital="Montgomery" >red</state>
  <state name="Alaska" 
    abbreviation="AK" 
    capital="Juneau" >blue</state>
  <state name="Arizona" 
    abbreviation="AZ" 
    capital="Phoenix" >green</state>
</capitals>';

SELECT Node.value('@name', 'varchar(100)') AS Name,
  Node.value('@abbreviation', 'varchar(2)') AS Abbreviation,
  Node.value('@capital', 'varchar(100)') AS Capital
FROM @xml.nodes('/capitals/state') TempXML (Node);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to use the . to get the inner text of the element. You can also use `text()[1]` There is a really good tutorial and examples on xPath in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_examples.asp).

```
DECLARE @xml XML; 

SET @xml = '<capitals> 
  <state name="Alabama"  
    abbreviation="AL"  
    capital="Montgomery" >red</state> 
  <state name="Alaska"  
    abbreviation="AK"  
    capital="Juneau" >blue</state> 
  <state name="Arizona"  
    abbreviation="AZ"  
    capital="Phoenix" >green</state> 
</capitals>'; 

SELECT Node.value('@name', 'varchar(100)') AS Name, 
  Node.value('@abbreviation', 'varchar(2)') AS Abbreviation, 
  Node.value('@capital', 'varchar(100)') AS Capital,
  Node.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS Color 
FROM @xml.nodes('/capitals/state') TempXML (Node);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I am silly:

```
 Node.value('.','varchar(100)') AS PoliticalDisposition
```